# My awk program to change spaces into tabs doesn't work

Tags: text-processing, awk

How to write a shell script which uses `awk` to read in the data file `students.txt` and output the data in the tabbed format as shown:

```
Surname Forename MSc Stream Date of Birth
Smith John IT 15.01.1986
Taylor Susan IT 04.05.1987
Thomas Steve MIT 19.04.1986
```

- Do not worry if tabbed columns don’t line up.
- The distance between each of (Surname, Forename, MSc Stream and Date of Birth) column is one tab.

**Question:**

Why this bellow code doesn't work for me?

```
awk 'BEGIN {IFS=" "} {OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' students.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?
Also, '{IFS=" "}' executed only before actual processing, while '{OFS="\t"}' executed after reading each row. And I don't see variable `IFS` in awk man page, did you mean `FS`? If so, it's already set to separate fields on whitespace, not just single space.

Comment: Please learn to use the formatting possibilities. You can see what I did to make your question more readable. Use the icons above the question box; click the `?` icon to see the available markup options.

Comment: @gelraen: Yup, you got it.

Comment: What about the header? How can you `awk` that?... I've barely touched on awk, so I'm guessing that would be a custom process for the first line in the main section... (but I've go no idea how)

Comment: Unclear: Given code works (but `IFS` is not a variable used by `awk`). It is unclear what "does not work" means.

Answer (score 8):

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" students.txt
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" students.txt
Surname Forename        MSc     Stream  Date    of      Birth
Smith   John    IT      15.01.1986
Taylor  Susan   IT      04.05.1987
Thomas  Steve   MIT     19.04.1986
```

#### Explanation

The reason it didn't work is because `awk` requires one of the fields to be changed before it applies the new output field separator.  The workaround for this defect (IMHO) is to just set a field to itself, hence the `$1=$1`

---

For this simple type of change, you're better off using `tr` or `sed`

```
tr -s ' \t' '\t*' < students.txt
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/\t/g' students.txt
```

Comment: Code from question works too (at least on GNU and FreeBSD implementations). "Defect" you described may take place because `print` prints $0 and $0 does not get rebuilt with new OFS when nothing was changed. Not sure is such behaviour a bug or it really should work this way. But `print $1,$2,$3,$4` still uses OFS to separate fields.

Comment: @galrean: you're right, this 'defect' is limited to `print $0` and its variations.

Comment: your code worked great in sed, < sed 's/ /\t/g' students.txt >. But the one in AWK didn't.!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
awk 'BEGIN {IFS=" "} {OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' students.txt
```

because you're setting OFS too late (not in the BEGIN block).  Do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' students.txt
```

Don't forget to change your header to have 4 space-separated fields:

```
Surname Forename MSc_Stream Date_of_Birth
```

Comment: I got this message (Syntax error at source line 1)..

Comment: @Host, did you cut and paste that code exactly? I do not get any syntax errors using any of the awk implementations at my disposal.

Comment: @asoundmove, I am sorry that I couldn't be active.. this was because of some unexpected condition! Thanks

Comment: @asoundmove: OP doesn't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: @Mikel, Ok, I did not remember the early restrictions. How about accepting an answer?