# Replace values in column that contain numbers

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file that looks as so:

```
chrom   start   stop    strand  isoform mu_codon    mut_codon2  more_info
chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C   300 903delC
chr22   43089715    43089717    -   NM_017436   CTT 79  241_243delTTC
chr12   53701873    53701875    -   NM_015665   TTC A   1292_1294delTTCinsA
```

I want to replace the values in the 7th column with a space if they contain a number and not a letter.

For example, here is my desired output:

```
chrom   start   stop    strand  isoform mu_codon    mut_codon2  more_info
chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C       903delC
chr22   43089715    43089717    -   NM_017436   CTT     241_243delTTC
chr12   53701873    53701875    -   NM_015665   TTC A   1292_1294delTTCinsA
```

I need to keep the space in my file so my columns are not altered. Any idea on how to do this? Maybe `awk`? I'm still learning these techniques. Can you explain your answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to preserve your columns you can change output field separator to be `tab` not `space` for example and it will be easier for further processing if you rely on columns count. So you can use following `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; }; { if ($7 ~ "^[0-9]*$") $7 = " "; else $7 = $7; }; 1'
```

In `BEGIN` section we are changing output field separator(`OFS`) to `tab`. In the next section we check if 7<sup>th</sup> contains only numbers and if yes we change value to `space`, if not keep the value. But with `$7 = $7` we are sure we reconstruct current line(record) because of changed `OFS`. Changing `OFS` ensures further processing with `awk` that output will contains 8 columns if field separator(`FS`) is set to `tab`.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. This is exactly what I needed and a perfect explanation. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Shouldn't this preserve my column 7? I tried recently to print column 7 with `awk '{print $7}' file` and wherever I had a space, it started to print column 8

Comment: try this: `awk -F"\t" '{ print $7 }'` if the output id from the above command

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{gsub("^[0-9]*$"," ",$7);$7=$7;OFS="\t";print}' file.txt
```

Comment: Does this not replace the entire field w/ a single space?

Comment: Yes this replaces entire field. This matches when the field has at least one number or more. But fails when the field contains any character. If you need to match against mix of numbers and characters use "[0-9]".

Comment: Well, right, but isn't the idea to replace only numbers with a space each? That's how I understand the question. To replace the entire field w/ a single space seems to be contrary to the purpose of the question.

Comment: I think the idea is just to replace the field with single space if is an integer.  Example also shows that field can be either an integer or a number. Not a mix of characters or numbers.

Comment: Not the field, the number: *I need to keep the space in my file so my columns are not altered.* Do you see in the example how when 2,3 numbers are removed they are replaced with 2,3 spaces? The column alignment remains the same in both the in/out examples.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many spaces we add. What's important is when we process this output later, it should list the seventh field as empty. So as in taliezin answer we can replace the OFS to tab for achieving better result.

Comment: I don't believe that's true. The output is not arranged in that way now - it is not a singly space-delimited format even before processing. What is it that gave you that idea? @taleizin suggests tabs, which will work up to point, but if the width spans tab stops it could go a little crazy. And anyway, his answer specifically addressed the problem for a reason.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't tested it thoroughly. Since for the lines where the fileds are unchanged awk doesn't assign OFS. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10606/my-awk-program-to-change-spaces-into-tabs-doesnt-work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
sed -e's/  *[^ 0-9]*/&\n/6;:n'      \
    -e's/\(\n[^ ]*\)[^ ]/\1 /;tn'   \
    -e's/\n//' <infile
```

Here's some `sed` to do it. The first thing we do is replace the 6th occurrence of one or more spaces followed by a sequence of zero or more `[^ 0-9]` not-space or numeric characters with itself followed by a newline.

Basically this means that if the 7th column consists entirely of characters other than spaces or numbers, `sed` will append a newline to it, else `sed` will prepend a newline to it.

In the next statement we replace all not-space characters immediately following a newline in pattern space with a space character each. Of course, this only happens at all when the newline is not already followed by a space character, as it will be if the seventh column was not numeric.

Last, we remove the inserted newline delimiter.

#### OUTPUT

```
chrom   start   stop    strand  isoform mu_codon    mut_codon   more_info
chr22   43089055    43089055    -   NM_017436   C       903delC
chr22   43089715    43089717    -   NM_017436   CTT     241_243delTTC
chr12   53701873    53701875    -   NM_015665   TTC A   1292_1294delTTCinsA
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {                     # Process line by line.
    my @F = split /(\s+)/;       # Split the line into @F, keep whitespace as members, too.
    $F[12] =~ s/./ /g            # Replace any character with space
        if $F[12] =~ /^[0-9]+$/; # if there are just digits.
    print @F;                    # Print the result.
}
```

Comment: eh, I'm unfamiliar with perl. Could you include the typical way to read in a file with perl?

Comment: Nevermind. I think I figured it out

Comment: @stellar01: That's just a warning. There's a line that contains less than 13 fields.

Comment: However, I keep getting this error: `Use of uninitialized value $F[12] in pattern match (m//) at ./removecharacters.pl line 8.`